# PHP netBeans - при работе с SabreDev глючит IDE

Tags: php, netbeans

Привет,
понадобилось в проект добавить поддержку WebDav - для этого использовал 
проект SabreDev, проект большой... и через некоторое время обнаружил, что
NetBeans от этого проекта заглючивает - пропадает возможность менять свойства проекта - пропадает кнопка ОК - для сохранения настроек в диалоговом окне.

Кто-то встречался с таким? 
ПС: постарался даже часть лишних классов удалить и все равно глючит... Хотя в отдельном проекте только под SabreDav все ОК. В проекте использую Zend v1/

Comment: Это просто фантастика, взял - и из этого кода сделал phar - и в таком виде к проекту подключил - все равно NetBeans глючит. Просто фантастика...

Comment: Более того - этот проект выбивает все остальные подключенные отдельные проекты... и в них появляется такая же ошибка.